# Nodejs Express https to http redirect not working

Tags: node.js

I installed an SSL certificate on my Nodejs server.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const https = require('https');
const app = require('express');

https.createServer({
    key: fs.readFileSync('./ssl/private.key'),
    ca:fs.readFileSync('./ssl/ca_bundle.crt'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('./ssl/certificate.crt')
}, app).listen(443);
```

Port 443 is the default listening for for https and port 8080 is the default listening port for http. My server is working fine and I can do https://www.example.net to access my site. But if I remove https or replace it with http , I wanted my server to auto redirect to `https` so I added:

```
app.use (function (req, res, next) {
    if (req.secure) {
            // request was via https, so do no special handling
            console.log(`Secure request`)
            next();
    } else {
            // request was via http, so redirect to https
            console.log(`Unsecure request`)
            res.redirect('https://' + req.headers.host + req.url);
    }
});
```

I can still connect file with https but if I remove it  I  get:

```
> dial tcp 312.312.d12.213:80: connectex: A connection attempt failed
> because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of
> time, or established connection failed because connected host has
> failed to respond.
```

Comment: Its because you are using por 8080 instead of port 80 (the one the browser is expecting), so it tries to connect to a port that is not listening (80 instead of 8080), try to access http://www.example.net:8080 and see how it works.

Comment: Also, the certs and the redirection, don't do it in node, put nginx in front, the idea is that the  nodejs app doesn't need to manage certificates or redirections, just a plain old http rest api.

Comment: @SebastiánEspinosa I am not using port 8080 I am using port 443 which is why https request is working

Comment: @SebastiánEspinosa I will use nginx. Thanks for letting me know. For now, I have posted the solution if not using nginx.

Answer (score 2):

I had to add

```
http.createServer(app).listen(80);
```

so that it can listen to unsecure request as well

Comment: Just another recommendation, you never NEVER want to run a service direct on port 80, because that's a reserved port so you will be running that with admin rights, so your service has admin rights too, that means if someone can inject code to your application, it will have root privileges, just trying to be helpful.